# Adding a Google Places SearchBox in a different View in Angular 2

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I was trying to add a google searchbox on a Side Navigation Bar using Angular  2.
I can't seem to get this done.

I want to use a different component for my searchbox like searchBox.component.ts

I have another component main.component.ts which has an instance of map defined inside

```
<div id="mapDiv" ></div>
```

I want to use the same map inside searchbox.component.ts so that i can search for places and add marker on the same map.
How can i achieve this ?

search.componnt.ts :

```
    import { Component,Output,EventEmitter,OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
    selector:'searchBox',
    templateUrl:'searchBox.component.html',
    styleUrls:['searchBox.component.css'],
})


declare var google: any;


export class searchBoxComponent implements OnInit{



    @Output() searchGeoCode :EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() closeButtonClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    input:any;
    searchBox:any;





    ngOnInit():void {
        let self= this;
        this.input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
        this.searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(self.input);
        this.searchBox.addListener('place_changed', function(){
          self.onSearchResultSelect(self);
        });
    }
    onSearchResultSelect(self:any) {
        let place:any;
        self.places = self.searchBox.getPlace();
        if (self.places == "") {
                return;
        }

        place = self.places;

        self.map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);

        self.searchedGeocode=this.map.getCenter().lat() + "," + this.map.getCenter().lng();
        let icon = {
            url: "./images/officeMarker.svg",
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30,30),
        };
        self.markernew=new google.maps.Marker({
            position: place.geometry.location,
            map: self.map,
            icon: icon,
            title: 'Current Marked Location'    
        });
    }
    OnClick() {
        this.input.value='';
        this.input.focus();
    }
}
```

My issue is how do i access the map variable defined in menu.component.ts in search.component.ts ?

menu.component.ts :

```
      initMap(){
   this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: this.zoom,
          center: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
          zoomControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT
            },
          mapTypeControl:false,
          streetViewControl:false,
          scrollWheelZoom : 'center',
        });
  }
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I didn't get your question, is it related to google places or to access the variable defined in menu in search component ?

Comment: @DanyY thank you for the reply . I wanted to access the variable defined in menu.component.ts from search.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

to interact between components, you should use the @Input and @Output. (for this condition one should contain the other)

```
  @Input() anyPropertyToPutInChild:string = "";


  @Output() search:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

your html will be like this :

```
    <search-component>
     <menu-component [anyPropertyToPutInChild]="value"  (search)="handleMenuInputInSearch($event)"></menu-component>
</search-component>
```

in menuComponent, you should call `search.emit('value')`

The value can be anything, in out case since we defined EventEmitter<**string**> it should be string.

in SearchComponent the function `handleMenuInputInSearch($event)` will be called with $event containing 'value' (the value emitted)